# Python block/halt on importing torch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have developed a deep-learning object-detect program based on `pytorch` and it works very well. Today I deploy this program on a PC, everything goes well, but the program cannot be launched. Debug and find out that, the program blocks, or halts, on importing `pytorch`.

Simply start a python prompt, type `import torch` and the prompt blocks. `top` command shows that CPU/memory usage is very low. Press `ctrl-c` cannot stop the prompt. While other library importing is fine. I have tried `pycrypto` and the one I wrote myself, all work but `pytorch` cannot.

I have deployed more than 100 times, but never meet this situation. I also tried to reinstall pytorch, from 1.6 to 1.4, torchvision from 0.7 to 0.5, still not work. No error printed, no complain shown.

Environment:

- OS: centos 7.4
- CUDA: 10.0
- NVIDIA driver: 440.82
- GPU: GTX 1660
- python: 3.6

`pytorch` version: 1.6 and 1.4.

Any information are welcome, thanks in advance.

---

Edit:

According to Szymon's idea, running `python3 foo.py`, which with only `import torch` in it, and press `ctrl-c`, the prompt prints:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import torch
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/platform.py", line 1068, in system
    return uname().system
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/platform.py", line 1034, in uname
    processor = _syscmd_uname('-p', '')
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/platform.py", line 788, in _syscmd_uname
    f = os.popen('uname %s 2> %s' % (option, DEV_NULL))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/os.py", line 980, in popen
    bufsize=buffering)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1318, in _execute_child
    part = os.read(errpipe_read, 50000)
```

It seems that python hangs on running `uname <option>`, so I tried `uname -a 2> /dev/null` on command line, it returned immediately and nothing strange. Also created a file named bar.py with the content below:

```
import platform
print(platform.system())
```

and run it with `python3`, works well, printed 'Linux'. I don't think it is the reason, maybe just a coincidence?

I also tried more times, other situation looked like running `import torch` in python prompt, could not kill the process and nothing printed. Once it printed `Soft lock up on CPU#4`, I thought it was caused by the test process in the last disconnected session.

Comment: What happens if you create a file `foo.py` with `import torch` only and run it from cmdline? If it hangs and you spam `ctrl+c` it should quit (or you can send `kill ID` or `kill -9 ID`). If it quits what is outputted as the last running operation?

Comment: @SzymonMaszke I have tried with your suggestion and updated the post. Any ideas with it?

Comment: so it always hangs and that is the error?  You said in your edit: "could not kill the process and nothing printed." which is unlikely if you hit `ctrl+c` many times until it crashes. It seems to hang on `platform.system()` call indeed. Any other processes running that could interfere with PyTorch? You should also ask this question on PyTorch's forums. Also did you use `conda` or `pip`? Also did you use installation instructions from PyTorch's starting locally or you were choosing specific wheels?

Answer (score -1):

In my case, in my directory with the main python file, there was also a file named `signal.py`, when i renamed it to `signal1.py` everything started working. So try to find some other python files in your directory and try rename it.

Comment: Hi Yonisen, your solution seems rather random and does not provide any context on how and why it might solve the problem. Could you please specify why this could help and what the mechanisms behind it are?